# run async task again after cancelling, is there a way?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

What happens is, I am fetching the data from web service.  Simultaneously 6 async tasks are running to get 6 different things. The problem is When first async task starts executing and I log out, and when I log in with different user, the first async task doesn't execute again. Am i forgetting something or it is this way only. How can I make the first async task execute again.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't reuse your `AsyncTask`. If you call `execute()` on the same `AsyncTask` twice, an exception will be thrown.

`AsyncTask`s are often specific to an `Activity` and aren't meant for long-term operations (such continuously fetching data from a web service). If you want your data to be fetched after exiting the activity, you'll need to use a `Service` instead.

Comment: There would be some way to do this.

Comment: Sorry, there isn't. If you call `execute()` twice on the same `AsyncTask` object you'll get an exception. It sounds like you want to use a `Service` maybe?

Comment: do you give the new user a `new AsyncTask`?

Comment: `mDownloadTask1 = new DownloadTask()` where `DownloadTask extends AsyncTask`... that's how you would "generally" assign your task a new `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Basically you just want to make sure you arent reusing the old `AsyncTask`... this might involve creating the task in `onResume` or something. But do whatever makes sense... I can't tell w/o seeing your code.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Add the `mDownloadTask1 = new DownloadTask()` to your answer. This is what people are looking for.